# Is it possible to create inheritance under one ID?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am wondering if it is possible to create different tables, that all fall under sone PK? My case is that I have around 15 different types of products. Each order may have multiple products (noted by Many-to-many table, where we connect PK of Order with PK of Product, and 3rd column indicating quantity, and 4th column indicating price). Now, is it possible to create a table structure, where each product category has its own table, but they all fall under one PK in many-to-many table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Look at the [JPA inheritance docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html). It sounds like you want either a Joined subclass strategy or a Table_per_class hierarchy strategy.

Simplified example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISC")
public abstract class SuperClass{
    // your common fields including primary key
    @Id
    private Long myKey;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FOO")
public class Foo extends SuperClass {
    // Foo fields. Can be empty, depending on use case
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR")
public class Bar extends SuperClass {
   // Bar fields
}   

@Entity
public class MyRelationshipClass {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyKey key;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_key")
    private MyOrder order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fooBarKey")
    private SuperClass fooBar;
    // other fields omitted
}

@Embeddable
public class MyKey {
    @Column(name="order_key")
    private Long order;

    @Column(name="fooBarKey")
    private Long fooBarKey;
}
```

In this case, you'll end up with a table for SuperClass with a myKey column, a DISC column, and whatever other shared columns you define. You will also get a Foo and Bar table with a myKey column and whatever columns they define in the subclass. Your MyRelationshipClass will have a table with a column for the MyOrder key (class omitted from example), a column for the Foo/Bar myKey, and whatever other columns you define. You can omit the Discriminator column, if you prefer.

If you want Foo and Bar in the same table as SuperClass, you change to `IneheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` and other wise the example remains the same. You **must** include the discriminator in this case. Using `JOINED` can have performance impacts for large volume tables or extensive inheritance mapping, but does provide more logical separation of data.

Note: Some JPA providers (i.e. Hibernate) allow you to define the Relationship mapping in the `EmbeddedId.` Not all do, so you need to define the relationship outside the `EmbeddedId` as above.

HTH